# How to test the results of a button press on iOS with unit testing?

Tags: ios, unit-testing, xctest

I have just started using unit tests and it works perfectly for non-visual parts. The application launches and it terminates almost immediately.

I want it to wait until a button appears and I want it to press it and I want to see If the newly loaded view is what I have expected.

I can do all of these within the application, but how will I make the test process wait until the finish without sleeping the thread?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sleeping the thread won't help... try Apple's 
[Automated UI Testing](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/InstrumentsUserGuide/UsingtheAutomationInstrument/UsingtheAutomationInstrument.html)